# Logical operator execution order

Tags: c++

I have though about operator overloading and come with an interesting code:

```
#include <iostream>

class A {
public:
    operator bool() {
        return true;
    }

    bool operator!() {
        return false;
    }
};

int main() {
    A a;

    if (!a) {
        std::cout << "HELLO";
    } else {
        std::cout << "WORLD";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

What will be called first and what after? And why? Is this described anywhere in the cppreference?

P.S. For downvoters and others who think I could not execute this code by myself. I could. I did. I have changed it many times to see it's behavior. So what? This is not an explanation. I have asked for a reference which **clearly** states what rule this code obeys. The information how it works on my machine does not answer the question - what if this is not even portable across different environments (OSes, maybe processors, and so on)?

Comment: Did you try it? https://ideone.com/sW8yEm

Comment: Nothing will be called first and after. Only `operator!` is called.

Comment: @mch yes I have tried it but I could not explain how it works to myself.

Comment: It will find the explict `! operator` and never consider conversion to `bool`. If you remove the `! operator` it will find the type conversion.

Comment: Sounds like you could use a [good C++ book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Comment: I think the downvotes are harsh. This is a well-written question, with compilable code. Yes, you could "try it", but the OP wants an explanation.

Comment: @Bathsheba not a down voter, but the try it by adding a breakpoint / print statement should reveal the answer to the first part of the question, making it "why is it the case" rather than "what is the answer and why" - it shows a lack of research

Comment: @UKMonkey - Maybe. But the rules of C++ can be so convoluted at times, I can see why one would ask. I mean, the OP places a breakpoint. They the see the operator gets called. Cool. Now they delete the operator... and it still works. I'd ask for a clarification in the OP's place.

Comment: Facetiously, *every* question can be closed due to lack of research.

Comment: @StoryTeller "the rules of C++ can be so convoluted at times" - at times?  ;)

Comment: @Bathsheba - Yeah. Let's just have everybody read ["Teach yourself C++ in 21 days"](http://abstrusegoose.com/strips/ars_longa_vita_brevis.png). ;)

Comment: @UKMonkey - unsigned integer addition is pretty straight forward :)

Comment: @StoryTeller: U wot? Howsabout `'a' + 'b'`?

Comment: @StoryTeller until it overflows, then people have to try to work out if it's UB (like the signed integer)

Comment: @UKMonkey: You learn about all that on the 22nd day.

Comment: @Bathsheba like driving a car, you only start learning after the test; when you're on your own; and when going at 90mph down the motorway wondering why on earth you can't stop in time

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How it works is simple. The compiler parses the source and sees `if(!a)`. It then checks if `A` defines an `operator!`. Just so happens that it does. So that gets called.

If it had seen `if(a)` it would have checked that an `A` is convertible to something which can be used in the condition of an `if`. Just so happens that it is indeed convertible.

If there had been no `operator!`, the compiler would have instead checked that an `A` can be converted to something which may be logically negated. *Then* the conversion to bool would have been performed.

---

BTW, the conversion will happen even in surprising places. For instance `a + 1` will compile. Not what we want, I think. It's best to allow it only where a `bool` is contextually expected. You do that by marking the conversion operator explicit:

```
explicit operator bool() {
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

`!a` is no more than syntactic sugar for `a.operator!()`, which you have defined: that's the compiler's preferred choice.

So the conversion to `bool` operator is never a candidate.

You could contrive the latter by writing

```
if (!(bool)a) {
```